# Divide the world in longitude/latitude rectangles of similar population

Tags: web-apps, library, scientific-computing, gis, geography

I am looking for a tool that can split the Earth's surface into rectangles of similar population.

That means oceans would get a few huge rectangles, as almost nobody live there, and cities would get a lot of small rectangles. I am not super strict about all rectangles having exactly the same population, but it must be the same order of magnitude. It is OK if a few rectangles have zero population, but no rectangle must have way more population than the median.

- Must give the list of rectangles with MinLongitude/MinLatitude/MaxLongitude/MaxLatitude for each.
- Ideally I should be able to specify how many humans per rectangle, or how many rectangles I want the world to be divided into. But providing a rough choices (for instance 10k humans per rectangle or 100k humans per rectangle etc) is acceptable.
- A rectangle can not cross the [180th meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/180th_meridian).
- Gratis, ideally open source.
- Preferably working offline on either Linux/Windows/Mac, but websites/webapps are OK as well, and libraries for any reasonably common programming language are OK too.
- The population data it relies on must be newer than 1990.

## Context

My script calls an API that gives information for a zone specified with a MinLongitude/MinLatitude to MaxLongitude/MaxLatitude "rectangle".

**Problem**: The API fails if the query asks for an area that contains too many inhabitants.

I can ask for a very large rectangle in Antarctica, but in Paris the rectangle must be tiny (maximum: 1 longitude degree * 1 latitude degree).

So, I modified my script to perform tiny requests (1 degree increments of both latitude and longitude). But that leads to another problem: With 360*180=64800 rectangles, it is taking days, as each request has a large overhead, and most requests return empty results as nobody lives there. So I need something more clever.

Comment: Maybe have a look / ask a question at https://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a [tree map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) - maybe that will help you in your search.  GIS is a good site; maybe also [open data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @albert: As seen at https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4382/1013 software recommendations are second-class citizens on the GIS site, and our site is the best place for them.

Comment: @Mawg: I guess you mean a [quadtree](https://github.com/Quadtree-org/Quadtree). A dichotomy-based quadtree might be an easy (albeit non-optimal) way to implement this indeed! I just hope someone has done it already haha

Comment: I am not so sure that I, but +1 for introducing me to a new concept :-) "a tree data structure useful to store 2D positional data" ... and ... "A quadtree is a tree data structure in which each internal node has exactly four children". Let the OP decide; being aware of both of of these will probably help his search

Comment: I don't think the data for this problem exists. You can get the population of the whole of Paris, or perhaps of a neighborhood of Paris, but likely not a rectangle defined by lines of longitude and latitude. That would essentially require knowing the address of each person.

Comment: @Kodiologist: Let's hope an answer will come up at https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/12753/world-population-density :-)

Comment: Why not solve your initial problem with API using classic dichotomy algorithm: query for a rectangle, if it fails (because too many inhabitants) then split the rectangle in 2 or 4 and query the new ones and apply the same behaviour... Start with the larger one you want.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: Failure is very expensive in terms of time and server resources.